# could not open file error with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, centos

I am using PostgreSQL and Centos

While in the the task database I am trying to do this

```
COPY CUSTOMERS TO '/home/cjones/cfolder/customers.txt' (DELIMITER '|');
```

I am getting the

Error: could not open file "/home/cjones/customers.txt" for writing: Permission denied

I have done ls -al and chmod the customers.txt to 777 and still getting this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of all requirements? [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)

1.

> You must have select privilege on the table whose values are read by
>   `COPY TO`

2.

> `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers,
>   since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has
>   privileges to access.

Plus, for the file to be accessible by the server it must lie on the same machine of course. And the directory must be accessible to the user the postgres server runs as, typically `postgres` (not only the file).

An alternative would be to use the [`\copy` meta-command of psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).

Comment: So I just did a select * from customers; and it showed data. So then I did the \copy instead of COPY and nothing went into the file.